# Rate of Liver Lesion formation following Cholecystectomy

Tags: liver, cholecystectomy

I am currently reading up on liver lesions, fibrosis, and cirrhosis. I am particularly interested in the rates of formation. For instance cancerous lesions can appear rapidly while more chronic diseases can result in a lesion forming over a couple of years. While reading, I came across this article which discussed the association of Cholecystectomy with Liver fibrosis [link](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fmed.2021.787777/full) which discusses the association of health, sex, age, and ethnicity to liver fibrosis in patients who have undergone Cholecystectomy. While reading through, I didn't see any details about the rate of formation.

As I am having difficulty locating this type of information in the literature. Does anyone have knowledge into the rates of developing Liver fibrosis following Cholecystectomy or does anyone have a link to an article which discusses rate of formation.

Comment: That’s a pretty specific pair; did you try googling  “association of liver fibrosis with cholecystectomy” on Google Scholar?

Comment: I did and found a variety of publications and medical papers discussing the association.  The problem for me was that most of these publications primarily focused on later time points and not progression of the disease.